# Writing Logs to Process Monitor (Sysinternal tool) for .NET(c#) Applications

Tags: c#, logging, sysinternals

I need some suggestions or code samples regarding how to add application logs to Process Monitor of sysinternals tools.I want to have a generic library that i can use to get the logs into the process monitor.

Answer (score 0):

[**Process Monitor**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) **monitors system activity** related to files, registry and network, **not application level logs**.

If your application will create log files, you'll be able to see those files in Process Monitor, along with their location.